# Adding new skip indexes

Tags: clickhouse

we already have a clickhouse cluster running on prod with 1 skip index, now we are trying to add 2 new indexes using this command : `ALTER TABLE ****** ON CLUSTER ***** ADD INDEX new_index1 eVar1 TYPE set(100) GRANULARITY 1, ADD INDEX new_index2 prop0 TYPE set(100) GRANULARITY 1;`
I read from the documentation that in order to apply these new indexes to the existing data, we need to run below query as well, so did the same :

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE ******* ON CLUSTER ****** FINAL
```

But still, we don't see any performance improvements in queries using these indexes, is there any way to debug what indexes are being used in a query? I tried EXPLAIN PLAN command but the version that we are using does not support indexes setting with EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1):

try to run clickhouse-client
and run

```
SET send_logs_level='trace';
SELECT ... your query;
```

it will show you which secondary index use and how it skips data parts

maybe your type of index or your column values distribution is not effective to apply index and index just not skip anything, or skip too low data parts during query execution

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/index), after adding new skip indexes, you would do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE *** ON CLUSTER *** MATERIALIZE INDEX name
```